# Quick way of selling at the trading post?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Is there a way to quickly sell goods at the trading post in GW2? I know there is the sell at trading post option by right clicking the desired item but that loads up the trading post every time and can not be considered a fast method to say the least.

Lets say i went exploring and came back with bags and bags full of stuff i want to sell.

Loading the trading post is fine but having to load the trading post every time over and over again takes a long time to do. I am aware that i dont have to close the window of the trading post every time but simply selecting the next item and selling it makes it take a long time for the trading post to come back with the prices.

My question today: Is there a quick way to sell stuff at the trading post besides right clicking.

Comment: So, you're saying you want to sell stuff at the trading post... without loading the trading post?

Comment: @ObliviousSage no loading the trading post is fine but having to load the trading post every time over and over again takes a long time to do. I am aware that i dont have to close the window of the trading post every time but simply selecting the next item and selling it makes it take a long time for the trading post to come back with the prices.

Comment: Sell the first item by right-clicking, then switch to the sell tab of the trading post and sell the rest of your stuff that way rather than by right-clicking on it in your inventory. It *has* to load the prices for things before you can sell them, there's no way to bypass that.

Comment: Do bear in mind the TP is pretty weak and can be very slow! Count yourself lucky, between pressing <kbd>O</kbd> and the thing loading fully can be up to 5 minutes for me!

Comment: Hmmm I always thought the TP was the same across all servers but for me the TP load max 5-10 seconds. Maybe I play during the off peak time for the "average worldwide peak time."

Comment: I always close it and retry if it takes more than 5 seconds. @ObliviousSage That should be an answer.

Comment: @Jay The TP is the same for every server. It uses a webservice to communicate with it. When a high peak moment occured, I actually had a TP screen with the ingame border and inside, a white internet page showing a 404-error. Nevertheless, using the TP (webservice) has a lot of variables. How many players are online? How many requests are going there? What is your internet connection? Etc. Do mind there are a lot of players and even sites continually retrieving data in it, such as gw2spidy. I'm already proud of GW2 for managing so far!

Answer (score 2):

Sell the first item by right-clicking on it. Then, once you're done selling it, **don't close the trading post.** Instead switch to the sell tab and it should list all the items in your inventory. Select them there to sell them, and you shouldn't need to reload the trading post every time.

Comment: Or start it off by opening the trading post (default hotkey is `O`), and click on the fourth tab.

Answer (score 0):

Open the trading post "O" when you login, enter the selling tab and never close the window again, drag it to the edge of the screen so it doesn't come in you way while you play. If you don't close the window or don't change the tab, the selling screen will update with items you loot and gather around the world, but every time you close the window or change tab, the selling screen will have to reload again.